# How to fit rectangular polygon into irregular polygon using R?

Tags: r, geometry, spatial, raster, r-sp

**How to fit a rectangular polygon into an irregular polygon? Or better; how to get the maximum-rectangular-polygon fitting into an irregular polygon?**

**Background**: I have got a bunch of overlapping raster files which represent different datatakes of a spaceborne sensorsystem. For further analysis, I want to get the maximum-rectangular-polygon (all 4 corners with 90degree angle) which fits into the footprints/outline of all these datasets, to mask and crop my datasets. In other words; How to fit a rectangular polygon of maximum size into the green outline (see image below)?

**Idea**: First get the outline or footprint for every dataset, then dissolve all the footprints to get the outline and **finally fit a rectangular polygon of maximum extent into that irregular polygon**

[image: the red lines represent the footprints of the datasets, the green lines represent the outline of the irregular polygon in which I want to fit a rectangular polygon of maximum size]

Comment: Can I just clarify? You want a single rectangle (I.e. 4 corners all 90 degrees) that completely encompasses every raster, and it should be the smallest possible rectangle that achieves this? Should it be aligned to the co-ordinate system (I.e. are you looking for the y values of the two bottom corners to be equal?

Comment: Or do you want the co-ordinates of the polygon shown in green in your figure?

Comment: @Allan Cameron thanks for your fast reply, i adjusted the question. I want a rectangular polygon of maximum size which is covered completely by the footprints of my raster datasets (it does not matter how often it is covered by the footprints, but is has to be covered at least once)!

Comment: @Allan Cameron I do not want the coordinates of the polygon shown in green in my figure

Comment: Does the output rectangle have to be aligned to the (lat-long?) coordinate axis or can it be rotated? I'd wager its a computationally hard problem to find the optimal solution because your green polygon is concave, so you could have all sorts of weird shapes. You could try an approach using `optim` but that can find a local optimum...

Comment: @Spacedman well, i get the point; it will be difficult to fit a **100% rectangular** polygon with exact **90degree** angles at all 4 corners into the irregular polygon due to crs issues... but actually i just want to get a study area in a rectangular format which is covered completely by my datasets/acquisitions of the sensor for further analysis...

Comment: Clarifications: 1. Is planar cartesian geometry sufficient? ie is this in a projected coordinate system or are you working in spherical (or ellipsoidal) eg lat-long? 2. if cartesian geometry, do you need a rectangle that is aligned with the axes of the cartesian geometry system? Or does rotation give us another degree of freedom?

Comment: i am working with a projected coordinate system; epsg4326.

Comment: In your application can we work with espg 4326 *as if it were* a cartesian coordinate system? What if the input polygon covers the poles? What if the input polygon is the equator? A polygon on a sphere does not have a well-defined inside and outside, it partitions the sphere into two parts.

Comment: And fourth time of asking, does your output rectangle have to align with the lat-long axes? ie does it have to be composed of lines parallel to lines of latitude and longitude, or can it be rotated (like some of the input rectangles seem to be)?

Comment: @Spacedman thanks again for further clarifying the question; I cannot figure out any reason why not to work like _if it_ were a cartesian coordinate system, as long as i receive a polygon which has crs epsg4326 in the end and matches my raster datasets. the input polygon neither covers the poles, nor does it cut/touch the equator.

Comment: @Spacedman it does not have to align with the lat-long axes.

Comment: I wrote an optimiser to try and find the best axis-aligned rectangle but if the polygon is a fat L shape its hard for an optimiser to search both arms of the L. I think some sort of fairly intelligent semi-exhaustive search over the answer space (x,y,w,h,a) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do what you need?

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(mapview)
raster1 <- raster(xmn=-2,xmx=0.1,ymn=50.3,ymx=51.5,vals=1)
raster2 <- raster(xmn=-2.1,xmx=0.5,ymn=50.4,ymx=51.4,vals=1)
raster3 <- raster(xmn=-2.2,xmx=-0.3,ymn=50.2,ymx=51.6,vals=1)

r1 <- extent(raster1)
r1p <- as(r1, 'SpatialPolygons')
r2 <- extent(raster2)
r2p <- as(r2, 'SpatialPolygons')
r3 <- extent(raster3)
r3p <- as(r3, 'SpatialPolygons')
r1p$data <- 1
r2p$data <- 2
r3p$data <- 3

rr <- bind(r1p, r2p, r3p)
rrsp <- as(extent(rr), 'SpatialPolygons')
rrsp$data <- 1
crs(rrsp) <- crs(r1p) <- crs(r2p) <- crs(r3p) <- crs(raster1)

mm <-
    mapview(rrsp, col.regions = 'green', col='green', alpha.regions = 0.1) + 
    mapview(r1p, col.regions = 'red', col='red', alpha.regions = 0.1) + 
    mapview(r2p, col.regions = 'red', col='red', alpha.regions = 0.1) + 
    mapview(r3p, col.regions = 'red', col='red', alpha.regions = 0.1)

mm
```

It finds the extents of each raster, makes spatial polygons from them, and then binds them together. The extent of this is then found, again as a spatial polygon.

The `mapview` code makes the following plot.

[image]

The green rectangle encompasses all of the rasters which are in red.